# Creating links for page transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a single page website. It has 3 'slides' like About/Music/Contact. The access to these slides is created with a dropdown menu. When you click the link in menu, the current page wrapper go `visibility: hidden` and through animation the following becomes visible. This works quite well, but everything happens on the root page, without changing the URL, which isn't user-friendly as if you want to share the link to the page you will always be redirected to the root.

So the question is: "How to make the url change without reloading the page (maybe through hash or smth) on the click?". Thanks in advance.

P.S. No code needed, just give me your way to make this, and I will add it into the code.

Comment: can i show a simple demo code ?

Answer (score 0):

Just check with this and take it if you want this

```js
function isElementInViewport (el) {
      //special bonus for those using jQuery
      if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
      }
      var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
      );
    }


    // click-to-scroll behavior
    $("a").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var section = this.href;
      var sectionClean = section.substring(section.indexOf("#"));
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(sectionClean).offset().top
      }, 1000, function () {
        window.location.hash = sectionClean;
      });
    });
    
    // listen for the scroll event
    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
      //console.log("onscroll event fired...");
      // check if the anchor elements are visible
      $(".common").each(function (idx, el) {
        if ( isElementInViewport(el) ) {
          // update the URL hash
          if (window.history.pushState) {
            var urlHash = "#" + $(el).attr("id");
            window.history.pushState(null, null, urlHash);
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
body {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
 
}
.common {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 height: 100vh;
 display: table;
}
.allbody {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}

a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 15px;
}
header {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #fff;
}
.common h2 {
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 10%;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
#firstDestination {
 background: #000;
}
#secondDestination {
 background: #999;
}
#thirdDestination {
 background: #ccc;
}
#fourthDestination {
 background: #c1c1c1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <a href="#firstDestination">first page</a>
 <a href="#secondDestination" >second page</a>
 <a href="#thirdDestination">third page</a>
 <a href="#fourthDestination">fourth page</a>
</header>


<div class="allbody">
 <div class="common" id="firstDestination" ><h2>First Page</h2></div>
 <div class="common" id="secondDestination"><h2>Second Page</h2></div>
 <div class="common" id="thirdDestination" ><h2>Third Page</h2></div>
 <div class="common" id="fourthDestination" ><h2>Fourth Page</h2></div> 

</div>
```

Comment: "Run code snippet" shown an error. `"message": "ReferenceError: $ is not defined",` at line 91, column 5.

Comment: That's because Jishnu hasn't included jQuery into the HTML.

Comment: Please Add a jQuery library to your html page.